# Why are some Chinese characters not displayed using the specified font?

Tags: fonts, character-encoding

I specified the font using:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Inziu Iosevka SC")
```

The expected result is (in notepad.exe):

[image]

But the result in Emacs is actually:

[image]

Only `举`, `头` and `乡` are displayed as specified.

The result of `describe-char` on the correctly rendered char `举` is:

```
             position: 374 of 386 (97%), column: 0
            character: 举 (displayed as 举) (codepoint 20030, #o47076, #x4e3e)
    preferred charset: chinese-gbk (GBK Chinese simplified.)
code point in charset: 0xBED9
               script: han
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, C:2-byte han, L:Left-to-right (strong), c:Chinese, |:line breakable
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET HEX-CODEPOINT" or "C-x 8 RET NAME"
          buffer code: #xE4 #xB8 #xBE
            file code: #xBE #xD9 (encoded by coding system chinese-gbk-dos)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    uniscribe:-outline-Inziu Iosevka SC-normal-normal-normal-mono-19-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1 (#x2493)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: CJK IDEOGRAPH-4E3E
  general-category: Lo (Letter, Other)
  decomposition: (20030) ('举')

There are text properties here:
  fontified            t
```

The result of `descirbe-char` on wrongly rendered char `床` is:

```
             position: 360 of 386 (93%), column: 0
            character: 床 (displayed as 床) (codepoint 24202, #o57212, #x5e8a)
    preferred charset: chinese-gbk (GBK Chinese simplified.)
code point in charset: 0xB4B2
               script: han
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, C:2-byte han, L:Left-to-right (strong), c:Chinese, h:Korean, j:Japanese, |:line breakable
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET HEX-CODEPOINT" or "C-x 8 RET NAME"
          buffer code: #xE5 #xBA #x8A
            file code: #xB4 #xB2 (encoded by coding system chinese-gbk-dos)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    uniscribe:-outline-BatangChe-normal-normal-normal-mono-19-*-*-*-c-*-gb2312.1980-0 (#x82AA)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: CJK IDEOGRAPH-5E8A
  general-category: Lo (Letter, Other)
  decomposition: (24202) ('床')

There are text properties here:
  fontified            t
```

So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure if you want to set global default font or only a font for *chinese-gbk* charset or *han* script, but maybe try `(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'chinese-gbk "Inziu Iosevka SC")` or `(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'han "Inziu Iosevka SC")`. You could also replace `"fontset-default"` with `"fontset-standard"` or `t`, but that depends on your needs. Check fontset docs http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fontsets.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not an expert, but can share you my configuration about Chinese font.

```
 (dolist (charset '(kana han symbol cjk-misc bopomofo))

            (set-fontset-font (frame-parameter nil 'font)

                               charset

                              (font-spec :family "FangSong" :size 15)))
```

Try this in your .emacs, see if any better.